# adding border lines onto image at the time image inserted into WS by VBA

Tags: image, vba, border

I have code to insert image into certain cell in WS as follow:

=============================================================

```
Sub LoadPict()

Dim Pict As String

Dim cl As Range

Pict = "D:\Picture.JPG"

Set Rng = Range("D2")

For Each cl In Rng

Set myPicture = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(Pict)

    With myPicture
                .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
                .Height = 150
                .Width = 144.75
                .Top = Rows(cl.Row).Top
                .Left = Columns(cl.Column).Left
                .PrintObject = True
    End With
Next
End If
End Sub
```

=============================================================

The Question is, What codes to be added, so that the picture I insert has Border Lines around it automatically.

Thank for taking time helping me.

Answer (score 2):

In Excel 2003 or later, try using the Shapes.AddPicture Method to add the image and the Shape.Line Property to set the border.

```
Sub LoadPict()
    Dim Pict As String
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim myPicture As Shape

    Pict = "D:\Picture.JPG"
    Set Rng = Range("D2")

    For Each cl In Rng
        Set myPicture = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Pict, msoFalse, msoTrue, cl.Left, cl.Top, 144.75, 150)
        With myPicture
            .Line.Weight = 8
            .Line.Visible = msoTrue
    Next
End Sub
```